# Change Ember.js RESTAdapter endpoint

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying set a different endpoint to RESTAdapter, looking at documentation, I try:

```
var store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    corsWithCredentials: true
  })
});

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  url: 'http://myapi.com:3000/'
});
```

My client side ember app are running at http://localhost.com:8000/, however the requests still are point to http://localhost.com:8000/ and not to http://myapi.com:3000.

Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely an older version of Ember Data you are using, take a look at the transition document and upgrade.  https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest ember? At least in [recent versions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_host-customization) it's called 'host':

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  host: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```